# How to change font to bold when mouse hovers over asp.net button?

Tags: asp.net

I have the following button in an ASP.NET page:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" Text="I AGREE" runat="server" />
```

and want the text "I AGREE" to change to bold whenever the user hovers the mouse over the button. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add a css class to the button

```
CssClass="button-style"
```

then add a css class

```
.button-style:hover{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

**edit** note the `.` now in `.button-style:hover`

Comment: sorry i missed the `.` from the class name. see my change!